# How to create a product view with slideshow in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, slideshow, iron-router, atmosphere.js

I am trying to create a Meteor js product page with a large product image where the image displayed changes based on the image selected from a set of 5 slideshow (or filmstrip) images. Basically similar to an amazon product page.
I am using iron:router.
I have created a product image page with a slideshow. Only problem is sizing the slideshow images so that they are smaller thumbnails and getting the images to display side-by-side and only under the product image (instead of spanning the whole page).

The slideshow I have is based on the **Slider Syncing** example from [slick slideshow](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) on atmosphere js - https://atmospherejs.com/udondan/slick.
My JS knowledge would only be basic in event that that is the root cause.

The code is below.

```js
import {
  Template
} from 'meteor/templating';
import {
  ReactiveVar
} from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

Template.carousel.rendered = function() {
  $('.slider-for').slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    arrows: false,
    fade: true
  });
  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true
  });
}
```

```css
#carousel {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

#carousel div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: orange;
}


/* dimensions of thumbnail grid */

.thumbnail {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid #021a40;
  background-color: #f0f;
}


/* dimensions of image within thumbnail grid */

.thumbnail-img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 0%;
}


/* dimensions of image within film strip */

.slider-img {
  max-width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>slick-sideshow</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to slick slideshow!</h1>
  <h2>Slider Syncing</h2>
  <hr/> {{> carousel}}
</body>

<template name="carousel">
     <div class="container js-container" >
        <div class="row">
      <div class="slider slider-for" id="carousel">
       <div class="thumbnail-img"><img src="slick_test1.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
       <div class="thumbnail-img"><img src="slick_test2.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
       <div class="thumbnail-img"><img src="slick_test3.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
       <div class="thumbnail-img"><img src="slick_test4.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
       <div class="thumbnail-img"><img src="slick_test5.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
      </div> <!-- / slider-for -->
       </div> <!-- row -->
     </div> <!-- / container -->
    
      <div class="container js-container">
          <div class="slider slider-nav">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <img class="slider-img" src="slick_test1.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <img class="slider-img" src="slick_test2.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                  <img class="slider-img" src="slick_test3.jpg" />
             </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                  <img class="slider-img" src="slick_test4.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                  <img class="slider-img" src="slick_test5.jpg" />
             </div>
          </div>  <!-- / slider-nav -->
     </div> <!-- / container -->
    </template>
```

I end up with this - 
[image: my slideshow attempt]

but am trying to get something like this [Amazon product image example](https://www.clippingpathindia.com/blog/2017/04/25/4-important-things-to-know-about-amazon-product-image-requirements/)

So the goal is to display a large product image with a strip of thumbnail images 
of alternate product views displayed below (and spanning) the product image - amz shows them to the side. The thumbnails are selectable causing the selected view to show as the main product image. They should be selectable either by clicking on them (ideal) and/or clicking an arrow or dot as shown in my example.

In my example the main issues are that:

- the product image is too small and not positioned in border
- the thumbnail images overlap the product image and the space between them is too large
- the thumbnail images are not clickable

Comment: It's not exactly clear, what result do you want to obtain. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @Styx I added more detail at end of post. Hopefully this is clear thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like the example below...

**the product image is too small and not positioned in border**
To position the image you can increase your containers' dimensions..

```
#carousel {
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height:   300px;
```

**the thumbnail images overlap the product image and the space between them is too large**

The thumbnails where overlapping actually because the slick-track element created by the library had a bigger height than its parent.. so just prevent this by setting a custom height.

```
.slider-for .slick-track{
     height:294px;
     }
```

**the thumbnail images are not clickable**

The thumbnails aren't clickable when you set different items in both the slide-for and the slide-nav container, to fix it just put the same items on both

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
      infinite: false, 
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
      arrows: false,
      fade: true
    });
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
      dots: true,
      arrows: true, 
      centerMode: true,
      focusOnSelect: true
    });
```

```css
.container{
  
 
}
#carousel {
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height:   300px;
    position: relative;
    /* top: 100px; */
    /* left: 100px; */
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}



.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
    color:  orange !important;
}


/* dimensions of thumbnail grid */
.thumbnail {
    width:  200px;
  height: 200px;
    padding:    1px;
    border: 3px solid #021a40;
    background-color:   #f0f;
} 

/* dimensions of image within thumbnail grid */
.thumbnail-img {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 0% 0%;
}

/* dimensions of image within film strip */
.slider-img {
  max-width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 0%;
}
.slider-nav{
  width:350px;
  margin:auto;
}
.slider-nav img {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:70px;
  margin:auto;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
 text-align:center;
 
}
.slick-slide img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    }
 .slider-for .slick-track{
 height:294px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick-theme.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.js"></script>

    <div class="container js-container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="slider slider-for" id="carousel">
            <div >
                       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500"  />
          </div>
          <div >
                       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-500-500-10.jpg"  />
          </div>
          <div >
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-500-500-6.jpg"  />
            </div>
          <div >
                   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-500-500-10.jpg"  />
          </div>
          <div >
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-500-500-2.jpg"  />
            </div>
        </div> <!-- / slider-for -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- / container -->

  <div class="container js-container">
      <div class="slider slider-nav">
          <div >
                       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500"  />
          </div>
          <div >
                       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-500-500-10.jpg"  />
          </div>
          <div >
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-500-500-6.jpg"  />
            </div>
          <div >
                   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-500-500-10.jpg"  />
          </div>
          <div >
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-500-500-2.jpg"  />
            </div>
            </div>  <!-- / slider-nav -->
    </div> <!-- / container -->
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. Apologies just seeing it now. I think you posted it before bounty expired in which case and given that it ticks all the boxes I'll see about applying bounty belatedly. I did get my own version in a better state (no longer overlaps for example) once I played around with CSS but not as 'slick' looking as yours. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I notice (and I had same problem) is that when you cycle from last to first image the first image does not display. Though when you cycle from second back to first, the first image will display. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your problem is mostly about CSS.
Giving appropriate width and heights to the images might probably gonna solve your problem.

You can use Chrome's developer console for doing some easy css changes and also you should check for console errors if there are any javascript errors.

Comment: Was thinking that it was CSS related. Will take a look at debugging layout.  Thx.